# Convert given relative urls to absolute urls

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to convert few given relative urls in the given html text to absolute urls.

The html text would be mixed with relative and absolute urls and I need the result html text which should only contain the absolute urls with following rules.

1. original html text contain mix of relative and absolute urls
2. need to convert `/test/1.html` into `https://www.example.com/test/1.html`
3. it should ignore the instance with absolute urls(both .com & .de) such as `http://www.example.com/test/xxx.html`,`https://www.example.com/test/xxx.html`, `https://www.example.de/test/xxx.html`, `http://www.example.de/test/xxx.html`

I know the best way to do that with `preg_replace` as I am using `PHP` and I tried the following code.

```
$server_url = "https://www.example.com";
$html = preg_replace('@(?<!https://www\.example\.com)(?<!http://www\.example\.com)(?<!https://www\.example\.de)(?<!http://www\.example\.de)/test@iU', $server_url.'/test', $html);
```

However, this doesn't give the desired results instead it has converted all the `/test` links including the existing absolute urls. So basically some urls were ended up like `http://www.example.dehttp://www.example.com/test/xxx.html`.

I'm not good at `regex`, please help me to find proper `regex` to get desired results.

Comment: Do all the relative urls start with `/`? Or can they also be test/1.html and can they have query string parameters?

Comment: why can't you just check that the URL starts with `http`, and if not, concatenate with `https://www.example.com`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird it is starting with `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the urls start with a forward slash, you might use:

```
(?<!\S)(?:/[^/\s]+)+/\S+\.html\S*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert what is directly on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `(?:/[^/\s]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching `/`, then not `/` or a whitespace char using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- `/\S+` Match `/` and 1+ times a non whitespace char
- `\.html\S*` Match .html as in the example data and 0+ times a non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQoBsM/1)

If you also want to match `/1.html` you could use change the quantifier into `)*` instead of `)+`

To match more extensions than `.html` you might specify what you would allow to match like `\.(?:html|jpg|png)` or perhaps use character class `\.[\w-()]` and add what you would allow to match.

Comment: what if it contain none html materials as well, such as jpg,png etc

Comment: @JanithChinthana Then you could either specify what you want to match using an alternation `(?:png|jpg)` or use `\w+` to match 1+ word chars or use `\S+` to match non whitespace chars (but that is a bit broad) See https://regex101.com/r/GQoBsM/2 or https://regex101.com/r/GQoBsM/3

Comment: forgive me if im so dump. what happen these links are lie on middle of large html text. It seems it is not detecting.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: let's say something like `<img src="/test/uploads/sample.jpg" />`

Comment: @JanithChinthana You might for example use an alternation to match urls starting with http(optional s) followed by optional www which you don't want. Then capture in a group what you want to keep https://regex101.com/r/EB0H8Y/2

Comment: @JanithChinthana You unselected the checkmark. Is is not working?

Answer (score 1):

This should match **root**-relative urls:

```
^(\/[^\/]{1}.*\.html)$
```

And the URL you want will be available in `$1`

https://regex101.com/r/E1evez/2

---

```
<?php
$urls = [
    '/test/1.html',
    'http://www.example.com/test/xxx.html',
    'https://www.example.de/test/xxx.html',
    '/relative/path/file.html'
];

foreach( $urls as $url )
{
    if( preg_match( '/^(\/[^\/]{1}.*\.html)$/', $url ) )
    {
        echo 'match: '.$url.PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no match: '.$url.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
match: /test/1.html
no match: http://www.example.com/test/xxx.html
no match: https://www.example.de/test/xxx.html
match: /relative/path/file.html
```